# ffmpeg C program to stream ts file through network without changing AV codecs

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, codec

I am trying to get a sample C source file as example which uses ffmpeg library APIs to stream a ts file as is without changing codec using rtp multicast

./ffmpeg -re -i test_av.ts -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f rtp_mpegts  rtp://237.255.5.3:5008

edit:
I am looking for sample C program(s) which could do something close the command I mentioned. I can modify & make required changes if it is somewhat close to what I am trying to achieve. I tried modifying the muxing.c in the doc, however didn't get how to copy codecs & stream through network using rtp multicast.

Comment: What is the question here? Is there an error? Post as much information as you can so we may help you

Comment: Apologies. I am looking for a sample C program(s) which could do something close the command I mentioned. I can modify & make required changes if it is somewhat close to what I am trying to achieve. I tried modifying the muxing.c in the doc, however didn't get how to copy codecs & stream through network using rtp multicast.